# How to make a discord bot correctly auto-capitalize the first letter of a string? regex

Tags: javascript, regex, discord.js

I've been trying to add this to my personal discord bot, to make it react with a sentence with corrected capitalized first letter as a response, using discord.js:

```
if (message.content.charAt(0) !== /[A-Z0-9]/g && message.content !== 'lol') {
    let UpfirstLetter = message.content.charAt(0).toUpperCase();
    let restOfLetters = message.content.slice(1);

    return message.channel.send(`*${UpfirstLetter}${restOfLetters}`);

}
```

But it keeps capitalizing the first letter despite already being so.
Like:

```
me: Good
bot: *Good
```

I'm new to regular expression. Does it has to do with that part, I assume?

P.S. Any suggestion for improving the filter effect of the regex is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in comment, something like

```
if ( message.content.charAt(0).toUpperCase() !== message.content.charAt(0) )
```

will also work for non ASCII characters, just deferring the responsibility of what a capital letter is to Javascript.

And as I don't have any idea of what a discord bot is, I prefer to tell you to store first letter in a variable, to ensure greater performance and code readability

```
const firstLetter = message.content.charAt(0);
if ( firstLetter !== firstLetter ) {
    //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is this `message.content.charAt(0) !== /[A-Z0-9]/g` this is checking to see if the character at the position 0 is equal to regex, not if it doesn't match, so  it would be the same as `'a' !== new RegExp()` which is always true.

What you want is the [`.test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) function so you can write it like this

`!/[A-Z0-9]/g.test(message.content.charAt(0))`

```js
if (!/[A-Z0-9]/g.test('g')) {
  console.log('Not Uppercase')
}

if (!/[A-Z0-9]/g.test('G')) {
  console.log("Won't hit this")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying where and why did I make the mistake. I didn't know about that method since, as already told, I'm new to this. Thanks again.

Comment: I'd like to propose you to change the condition with something like `if message.content.charAt(0).toUpperCase() !== message.content.charAt(0)` ... It will be working even for non ASCII characters !

Comment: @farvilain Wow, a simple yet very creative way of addressing such issue. Thank you. I think it's worth more than a comment. Could you write it as an answer? It's really a good alternative.